# SonarQube BuildBreaker plugin not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube

I have installed SonarQube 4.1.1, Jenkins ver. 1.533 and the BuildBreaker plugin.

I have set up two alerts in Sonar where if a certain threshold are reached it should flag the build on Jenkins as ERROR so I would expect to the something like this below in the log:

```
[ERROR] Coverage < 50%
[ERROR] Class complexity > 20
[INFO]  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO]  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  Can not execute Sonar

Embedded error: Alert thresholds are hit (2).
```

The two alerts I have set is Blocker issues > 20 and Critical issues > 30.
And I have more then 20 Critical issues.

Yet when I run a Jenkins build in Preview mode sonar.analysis.mode=preview the build is successful.

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 8:30.621s
Final Memory: 51M/916M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Recording test results
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Any ideas as to why Jenkins is not picking up the alerts from the BuildBreaker plugin?
If I go to the SonarQube Dashboard I can see the Critical issue > 30 alert has been reached.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

IIRC build breaker is excluded by default in preview mode. You will want to check your preview configuration.

Comment: Hi Minthfindel thank you for your answer.  But I am not sure what you are referring to.  These are the properties I have set in Jenkins: `# Language
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

#Exclude the JUnit tests
sonar.exclusions=test/**/*.java,**/*Test.java,**/Test*

#Code analysis results are not stored on database
sonar.analysis.mode=preview
What other property do I need to add to get the build breaker to work?  Thanks

Comment: The `sonar.preview.excludePlugins` property is used to declare plugins that should be excluded from preview mode. By default, it is set to `buildstability,devcockpit,pdfreport,report,scmactivity,views,jira`, with `buildbreaker` added as of SQ 4.2. But you might want to check your thresholds: if the "Critical Issues" threshold is 30, it won't trigger if you have only 20.

Comment: Build Breaker is not in my preview exclusion list, yet stil does not work when run in incremental or preview analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Since SonarQube 4.1, the buildbreaker plugin is excluded from incremental and preview execution mode by default. You may check your SonarQube settings ("Settings" -> "General Settings" -> "General") and add "buildBreaker" into "Plugins accepted for Preview and Incremental modes" input box, save the setting and try again.

Comment: This doesn't work either. They have permanently disabled buildbreaker plugin from incremental/preview analysis.

Comment: Heres the link to documentation for more details: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Build+Breaker+Plugin

Comment: Thanks to point it out. Do you have any idea why it was deprecated? In my point of view this plugin is very valuable to CI process.

Comment: The built in Build Breaker Plugin for SonarQube has retired in 5.1 release. This is a workaround to achieve the same using SonarQube REST APIs. https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/sonarqube-build-breaker